# Conditional free shipping based on shipping class and minimal amount in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

In woocommerce regarding Shipping methods, I am trying to have the following:

- Products A only in cart: set with "Free shipping"
- Products B only in cart: set with:

  - Flat rate amount of 15 if Products B purchased amount is less than 200
  - Free shipping if Products B purchased amount reaches 200 or more..
- Products A + Products B are in cart at the same time: "Free Shipping" without any amount restriction.

I have tried by using flat rate and shipping classes I am getting like if product A and product B is there then if the cart doesn't reach 200 it is taking 15 shipping charge.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** To make it work first you will need:

- To add a "Free" shipping class *(first)*,
- To enable 2 shipping methods: "Free shipping" and "Flat rate",
- In your products with Free shipping will need to be set **with the shipping class "Free"**,
- In your other product **will not have any defined shipping class**.

1. For the "free shipping" method, **you will not add any restrictions amount to it**.
2. For the "Flat rate" shipping method, you will set it as in this screen shot:

[image]

3. The magic will be done by the following code that will make the rest:

   add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'conditional_free_shipping', 10, 2);
   function conditional_free_shipping( $rates, $package ){
   if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
   return $rates;

   ```
    ## -- Your settings below -- ##

    $shipping_class  = 'free'; // "Free" shipping class products
    $min_free_amount = 200;    // Minimal Free shipping amount for normal products

    ## -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- ##

    $has_free = false; // Initializing
    $products_total = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() == $shipping_class ) {
            $has_free = true;
        } else {
            // Get the total purchased amount for normal product
            $products_total += $cart_item['line_total'] + $cart_item['line_tax'];
        }
    }

    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // 1. Only Free shipping products in cart OR both products kind in cart
        if( $has_free ) {
            if( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id )
                unset( $rates[$rate_key] ); // Remove flat rate
        }
        // 2. Only normal products in cart
        else {
            // A. If it's under the min amount
            if( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id && $products_total < $min_free_amount )
                unset( $rates[$rate_key] ); // Remove Free shipping
            // B. When min amount is reached
            elseif( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id && $products_total >= $min_free_amount )
                unset( $rates[$rate_key] ); // Remove flat rate
        }
    }
    return $rates;
   ```

   }

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

> **You might need to refresh shipping cached data:** disable, save and enable, save related shipping methods for the current shipping zone, in Woocommerce shipping settings.

Comment: This procedure is not working as per my requirement previously i was getting free if cart is reaching 200 but this procedure is not working

Comment: @MohammedSaif This code is tested and really works… The used hook is the correct hook. Now may be you want the total cart amount instead of the normal products total amount.

Comment: No No I want if the product A free shipping and Product B with 15 shipping charge both are there in the cart then free shipping should be applied instead of charge shipping for the most expensive shipping class

Comment: above procedure making free shipping if the cart reaches 200.. but i need if product A is there which is of free shipping with other products which cos flat rate 15 then there should be free shipping not flat rate whether the cart goes 200 or not it should be free shipping

Answer (score 0):

I did some improvement in the code now it is working fine..

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'conditional_free_shipping', 10, 2);
function conditional_free_shipping( $rates, $package ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return $rates;

    ## -- Your settings bellow -- ##

    $shipping_class  = 'free'; // "Free" shipping class products
    $min_free_amount = 200;    // Minimal Free shipping amount for normal products

    ## -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- ##

    $has_normal = $has_free = false; // Initializing
    $products_total = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() == $shipping_class ) {
            $has_free = true;
        } else {
            $has_normal = true;
            // Get the total purchased amount for normal product
            $products_total += $cart_item['line_total'] + $cart_item['line_tax'];
        }
    }

    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // 1. Only Free shipping products in cart
        if( $has_free && ! $has_normal ) {
            if( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id )
                unset( $rates[$rate_key] ); // Remove flat rate



        }

        elseif(( $has_free && $has_normal )){
             if( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id && $products_total <= $min_free_amount )
                unset( $rates[$rate_key] );
                }


        // 2. Only normal products in cart OR Both products kind in cart
        elseif( ( ! $has_free && $has_normal )  ) {
            // A. If it's under the min amount
            if( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id && $products_total < $min_free_amount )
                unset( $rates[$rate_key] ); // Remove Free shipping
            // B. When min amount is reached
            elseif( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id && $products_total >= $min_free_amount )
                unset( $rates[$rate_key] ); // Remove flat rate
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```